# Flask flashes appear on development server, but not with uWSGI/Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have been learning Flask by making a little website and using the built in flask server that runs with python. I have a page where you press a button, and it flashes a message using the flash system inside of flask. These flashes work fine when I am using the built in flask server on my windows machine. However, I have deployed the website to a Linux server, using uWSGI which goes through Nginx. My issue is that when I access this server, the flashes don't work. Most things like loading pages work fine on both servers, but flashing is broken. I don't see any error messages from uWSGI's logs.

The code I am using for the flash is implemented as follows:

```
flash("Made new post.")
return redirect(url_for("posts"))
```

The redirect takes me to the correct page, and if I run a print() statement before the redirect the statements are clearly being reached, the flash just doesn't do anything.
The main other issue I am running into is with sessions and trying to store session variables. Nothing happens when I try to do this either. (but it works on my personal machine)

Any ideas why this might be, or at least a way to get an error message from uWSGI?

Answer (score 0):

To properly set cookies (cookies are what make message Flashing work), both nginx and the Flask application need to agree on the server name.

So make sure your `server_name` in nginx.conf matches [`SERVER_NAME`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#SERVER_NAME) (or
`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`, if set) in your flask configuration.

There are also limits enforced by nginx on the size of cookies, but this should only be a problem if your flashed messages are really large.

Comment: Thanks. I set the `SERVER_NAME` property so that it matches my Nginx configuration, but it still isn't working. I did put this test website on a subdomain, which may be related.  It's also worth noting I don't have SSL configured.

Comment: Yeah, the `server_name` is sensitive to, and should match, the name in the URL. Does this also match?

Comment: Yes. The `server_name`, the name in Nginx, and the name in my browser are all the same.